# How to create an extensible app in React Native

Tags: android, ios, swift, react-native, plugins

I'm trying to make my app modular. There will be a core extensible base module. In Android, I plan on having a sub-directory in the `assets` folder, called `plugins`, where extensions to the core app will be downloaded into as **.apk**s.

How can I create such a modular app in **React Native**?

I have a working implementation in Android. I currently have my app loading external plugins that implement an interface:

```
public interface IDynamicModule {
  String getText();
}
```

I am loading the APKs using **`DexClassLoader`** :

```
class ModuleLoader(val cacheDir: String) {

    fun load(dex: File, cls: String = "com.example.dynamicmodule.DynamicModule"): IDynamicModule {

        try {
            val classLoader = DexClassLoader(dex.absolutePath, cacheDir,
                    null, this.javaClass.classLoader)

            val moduleClass = classLoader.loadClass(cls)
            if (IDynamicModule::class.java.isAssignableFrom(moduleClass)) {
                return moduleClass.newInstance() as IDynamicModule
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("ModuleLoader", e.message, e)
        }

        return IDynamicModule { "Failed to load" }
    }    
}
```

Thank you all in advance.